# Image Preview using AJAX in PHP

Tags: php, ajax

How should i create a preview of image to be uploaded before it is actually submitted using AJAX in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Without uploading the image, this is going to be impossible in JavaScript as far as I can see, because security limitations are going to prevent you from determining the selected file in the file upload, and embedding that file in an `img` tag (as it used to be possible five years ago.)

You will be more lucky with Flash-based uploaders. I have seen some that offer the kind of functionality you want.

Update: [Here](http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html)'s one that offers a preview function. From what I can see, it base64 encodes the local image and serves it to the surrounding HTML page as a inline data `<img>` tag. This is great because it might integrate well into your site. It does *not* work with any version of Internet Explorer, though.

[**Here**](http://www.adylevy.com/index.php/2009/07/22/multiple-files-uploader-with-preview-on-client-side/)'s a fully Flash based solution that does previews in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you first have to **upload** the document to server. Than you can show like.

```
<img src="uploads/file1_12224.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The "file" input type doesn't expose the local file location of the file to be uploaded. It does "appear" to because as a user you can see the location, but the web page never knows this value. Without the local file address, you can't show a preview of the image on the web page using plain HTML or JavaScript.